# modifying variables in a class

Tags: java

So say I've got a class, and its got a few variables that I want to be able to increment within a few methods in the class. How do I go about editing them?

I've been trying to do this, but its not working. My understanding from doing some reading is that java passes a copy of the object, so when I edited it in the method it doesn't actually edited the original value. It just makes adjustments to the copy and then once its done the value disappears.

I did read something about having to return the value from the method to update the original, but then I'm a bit confused as to how I would go about calling it.

Comment: Objects are not copied automatically when they are passed to methods.

Answer (score 1):

Simple example:

```
public class Thing {
    private int someInt = 0; // optional, can be left unset as well if you remember to assign it in the constructor or some method.

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thing yourobj = new Thing();
        System.out.println("Then: "+yourobj.getThatInt());
        yourobj.increment();
        System.out.println("Now: "+yourobj.getThatInt());
    }

    public int getThatInt() {
        return this.someInt;
    }

    public void increment() {
        this.someInt += 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: what if the class is being called from another class? so what im trying to do is compare two array values, if they match increment one value, if they dont increment another. but i cant get the method to actually update the values, regardless of what i do it always returns 0 for both

Comment: Suppose you have a class with two integers, `private int fails`and `private int successes`, in your method for comparing you would do something like this (assuming you have getters and setters for each of these values in whatever class/object you store them in) `if(value1==value2) { someObject.setSuccesses(someObject.getSuccesses()+1); } else { someObject.setFails(someObject.getFails()+1; }` that's one way of doing it, but there are others (such as declaring a public variable and just calling `someObject.successes+=1`)